# Pandas: Remove rows where all values equal a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with regex search results. I need to remove any row where there were ***no*** matches for ***any*** of the terms. Not all columns are search results, only columns 2 - 6.

Have tried ( NF = "Not Found" ):

```
cond1 = (df['term1'] != "NF") & (df['term2'] != "NF") & (df['term3'] != "NF") & (df['term4'] != "NF") & (df['term5'] != "NF")
df_pos_results = df[cond1]
```

For some reason this is removing positive results.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `.all`:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, 1:5].ne('NF').all(axis=1)]
```

That will remove all rows where every value in the row is equal to `NF`.

For multiple values:

```
df = df[~df.iloc[:, 1:5].isin(['NF', 'ABC', 'DEF']).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: This is overmatching somehow. Should be roughly 1800 results and it's showing 69.

Comment: Are you sure it should be *every* column? Maybe only the columns that begin with `term`?

Comment: It's only columns 2 - 6. If all 5 of these equal NF, the row should be dropped.

Comment: Okay, check now.